# Paypal Recurring Payment Development

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm currently integrating the paypal recurring payment. I have some questions about integrating paypal system.

1. Users need to create the paypal account for recurring payment system?
2. Can we use this "Try the buttons" integration for paypal recurring payment?
   https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/
3. If users signup with the credit card without creating paypal account, can we get the credit card brand. last 4 digits, and expiration date?
4. Can we use php api to create recurring system with paypal account or credit cards?
5. Can we use api to apply subscriptions coupons?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you integrated? I am still facing some issue in same situation,

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Haven't seen that before, but you can simulate everything in a sandbox if that's what you are looking for.
3. If I recall correctly you don't get the last 4 digits, but you do get the expiration date.
4. Yes
5. Not sure, didn't have to implement that.